# Grails multi-environment config block

Tags: grails, groovy

Syntax sugar / clever hack question.

I'd like to write multi-environment config blocks in a more elegant / more concise way than the following (which works, but is ugly):

```
environments {
    development {
        // long list of directives
    }
    ["staging", "production"].each{"$it"{  // <- ugly!
        // another long list of directives
    }}
}
```

I tried to hack together some DSL like the following, adding `propertyMissing` to `EnvironmentBlockEvaluator.metaClass` but I couldn't do it. The main problem is that bare words in the config file (such as `staging`) are turned into empty `groovy.util.ConfigObject` before the closure in `environments { }` has a chance to do anything on them. I'm not sure why.

```
(staging | production) {
    // directives
}
```

Any clever ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `switch` block in `resources.groovy` - I think it would work for `Config.groovy` as well (although haven't actually tested it).

```
switch (Environment.current) {
    case Environment.DEVELOPMENT:
    case Environment.TEST:
    //stuff for dev & test environments
    break
    default:
    //production stuff
}
```

Only marginally easier on the eye than `["staging", "production"].each{"$it"...` though.